# Cookbook for CloudHealth Agent installation

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to write a custom chef cookbook to install Cloudhealth Agent on Linux instances.

```
registration_code = "unique-registration-code"

execute "Install Agent" do
  command "wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/remote-collector/agent/install_cht_perfmon.sh -O install_cht_perfmon.sh; sh install_cht_perfmon.sh 14 #{registration_code} aws; exit 0"
  ignore_failure true
  not_if "test -d /opt/cht_perfmon"
  only_if { node.attribute?(:ec2) }
end
```

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: Need some help in writing cookbook. :)

Comment: That is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Please consider hiring a consultant/trainer or running through the Chef tutorials.